# Grav 1.7 Installation fails bc of call to undefined method

Tags: php, grav, uberspace

#### Cross post from https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/3523

(don't kill me, I didn't know that it's frowned upon)

I am not sure if this is the place to ask for help, so tell me if it's not (and maybe where to ask).

I am trying to update to the latest Grav release `1.7.29` from (originally `1.6.24`, while troubleshooting today updated to) `1.6.31` (using direct-install.

I tried updating with `self-upgrade` and `direct-install <latestVersionURL>`.
But, while trying to install, it gives me the following error:

> Installing upgrade... [30-Jan-2022 17:04:37 Europe/Cityxy] PHP Fatal
> error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Grav\Common\Utils::basename() in
> /var/www/virtual/name/html/tmp/Grav-61f6b713f0bb9/zip/grav-update/system/src/Grav/Installer/VersionUpdate.php:29
>
> Stack trace:
>
> **#0** /var/www/virtual/name/html/tmp/Grav-61f6b713f0bb9/zip/grav-update/system/src/Grav/Installer/VersionUpdater.php(126):
> Grav\Installer\VersionUpdate->__construct('/var/www/virtua...',
> Object(Grav\Installer\VersionUpdater))
> **#1** /var/www/virtual/name/html/tmp/Grav-61f6b713f0bb9/zip/grav-update/system/src/Grav/Installer/VersionUpdater.php(38):
> Grav\Installer\VersionUpdater->loadUpdates()
> **#2** /var/www/virtual/name/html/tmp/Grav-61f6b713f0bb9/zip/grav-update/system/src/Grav/Installer/Install.php(239):
> Grav\Installer\VersionUpdater->__construct('core/grav',
> '/var/www/virtua...', '1.7.29', Object(Grav\Installer\Versions))
> **#3** /var/www/virtual/name/html/tmp/Grav-61f6b713f0bb9/zip/grav-update/system/src/Grav/Installer/Install.php(184):
> Grav\Installer\Install->prepare()
> **#4** /var/www/virtual/name/html/system/src/Gra in /var/www/virtual/eduref/html/tmp/Grav-61f6b713f0bb9/zip/grav-update/system/src/Grav/Installer/VersionUpdate.php
> on line 29

From my understanding the files between versions have been changed, and looking at the [Grav documentation](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/api#class-gravcommonuri), the called method `basenames()` is now in `Grav/Common/URI`, not in `Grav/Common/Utils`.

So I assume I located the problem, but have no idea on fixing it. Since I am not very well versed on this whole topic of managing websites (never set up the site, only maintaining it), I would really appreciate a safe answer on how to update Grav to the newest version which doesn't risk me destroying the functioning of the website.

Thank you for helping! :)

*Tried with:*
**PHP**: 7.3 & 7.4
**Grav**: 1.6.24 & 1.6.31
**Admin**: 1.9.10
**Host**: Uberspace
via SSH

Comment: Cross posting the exact same question on Grav's repo https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/3523 and here on SO a few minutes apart is often not really appreciated... See this meta post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site/141824#141824

Comment: Well, you learn something new everyday... I'll mark it as a crosspost and will remember it for future posts

Answer (score 0):

Particular issue fixed:
https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/3523

following issue open:
https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/3532